# AT commands to hm10 over bluetooth with android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, at-command, hm-10

Hey guys am working with a project and i want to know is it possible to send AT commands to hm-10 ble device directly from my android app over bluetooth without using any micro controller and if yes then how????

Comment: It is this HW you are talking about? If so there is already an app for that. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.irobotlabs.hmble

Comment: or is it this product you are using? https://evothings.com/control-an-led-using-hm-10-ble-module-an-arduino-and-a-mobile-app/

Comment: Thanks harsmar for your kind reply actually i want to embed this functionality in my app and i found the solution hm10 is alwaz is in at mode if u send data it will be read as data but if u send at commands as string then it treats that string as at commands and executes them

Comment: I am using https://evothings.com/control-an-led-using-hm-10-ble-module-an-arduino-and-a-mobile-app/ this product along with android app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if any one trying this in future, the answer is yes we can just send a string to hm-10 as "AT\r\n" and it will respond with OK.