# How can I get data from bluetooth module by AT commands on Android App?

Tags: android, at-command

I have a digital scale and one of [this kind of bluetooth adapter](https://buy.serialio.com/collections/adapters/products/bluesnap-smart-bluetooth-4-0-ble-to-rs232-adapter).

They are connected by RS232. And the bluetooth adapter can be manipulated by `AT commands`.

I've found [this project](https://github.com/ninglvfeihong/Android-AT-command-apk) on Github. But this is just for Wifi module, I guess. I need to input `host name` and `port number`.
 But I need to connect bluetooth module.

I'd like to implement [this kind of feature](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cXqzyic9G2o). But I only needs the value of weight from the digital scale. The user will not type anything but send AT commands under the hood on the app and then get the weight value.

If there is alternative way, please let me know!

similar questions:

[Android communicating to HFP device via AT commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26342372/android-communicating-to-hfp-device-via-at-commands?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[AT commands to hm10 over bluetooth with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493234/at-commands-to-hm10-over-bluetooth-with-android)

[How do you send an extended-ascii AT-command (CCh) from Android bluetooth to a serial device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650831/how-do-you-send-an-extended-ascii-at-command-cch-from-android-bluetooth-to-a-s)

Comment: I am also facing same issue, may I know have you got solution